# DB2 XML Select multiple rows in Single statements

Tags: db2, db2-400

In My code,

```
SELECT X.DEP_ID
              FROM (SELECT XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT '<root><DEP_ID>1000000004</DEP_ID><DEP_ID>1000000005</DEP_ID></root>') AS ELEMENT_VALUE
                    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) AS A,
                   XMLTABLE (
                      '$d/root'
                      PASSING Element_value AS "d"
                      COLUMNS 
                      DEP_ID  VARCHAR (10)  PATH 'DEP_ID'
                                 ) AS X;
```

Need as result of:

```
DEP_ID

1000000004
1000000005
```

If its single values means it working that means only one DEP_ID in xml.
But Multiple return means it will show error.

How to get the output as like above in db2.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong `row-xquery-expression-constant`.
Try this:

```
SELECT X.DEP_ID
FROM 
(
SELECT XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT '<root><DEP_ID>1000000004</DEP_ID><DEP_ID>1000000005</DEP_ID></root>') AS ELEMENT_VALUE
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
) AS A
, XMLTABLE 
(
'$d/root/DEP_ID' PASSING Element_value AS "d"
COLUMNS 
DEP_ID  VARCHAR (10)  PATH '.'
) AS X;
```

Comment: if  its multiple column means '<root><DEP_ID>1000000004</DEP_ID><EMP_ID>123</EMP_ID><DEP_ID>1000000005</DEP_ID><EMP_ID>1456</EMP_ID></root>'

Comment: I didn't get the question. What's the strange document, where departments and employees are on the same level? What's the expected table output from such a document?

Comment: '$d/root/DEP_ID' PASSING Element_value AS "d" in this section you mentioned only DEP_ID for my scenario i have more columns.

Ex:'<root><DEP_ID>1000000004</DEP_ID><EMP_ID>123</EMP_ID><DEP_ID>1000000005</DEP_ID><EMP_ID>1456</EMP_ID></root>'

Comment: Expected Result is:
DEP_ID              EMP ID

1000000004      123

1000000005      1456

Comment: Why is `emp_id=123` in the same row as `dep_id=1000000004`, and not with `dep_id=1000000005`? Just because of this `emp_id` element follows the `dep_id=1000000004` at the same level? You may have the following document structure to "bind" employees to departments, but not in the way you mentioned. `<root>
  <DEP_ID id="1000000004">
    <EMP_ID>123</EMP_ID>
  </DEP_ID>
  <DEP_ID id="1000000005">
    <EMP_ID>456</EMP_ID>
  </DEP_ID>
</root>`

Comment: SELECT X.DEP_ID
FROM 
(
SELECT XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT '<root><DEP_ID>1000000004</DEP_ID><EMP_ID>123</EMP_ID><DEP_ID>1000000005</DEP_ID><EMP_ID>321</EMP_ID></root>') AS ELEMENT_VALUE
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
) AS A
, XMLTABLE 
(
'$d/root/DEP_ID' PASSING Element_value AS "d"
COLUMNS 
DEP_ID  VARCHAR (10)  PATH '.'
) AS X;


How to handle this scenario.
Can u please explain.
Not getting your Comments.

Comment: It's not possible to get the desired output from the document you mentioned, because it's not possible to understand from the document, which department a particular employee belongs to.